# httpClient.PostAsync() performs GET request anyway

Tags: c#, .net, http, httpclient

I really am not sure what is happening.
I'm using an HttpClient to post XML content to a remote server using the `PostAsync` method like this:

```cs
using var content = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
using var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(string.Empty, content);
```

... where `payload` is a string, and relative uri is empty because I just need to call base uri of httpclient.

I can perform same request in Postman and it works fine.
The issue is, for some reason httpclient actually performs a GET request instead of POST, and ignores content whatsoever:

[image: screenshot]

I've checked in Postman, and it seems like it is a normal response from the server to GET request.

I've also tried

```cs
using var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, string.Empty){Content = content});
```

... and it gives the same result.

This looks like a very weird issue to me, as I've never seen http client behaving like this in the past. Could anyone please explain why is this happening? Thanks!

Comment: So, are you sending null content, or that is the HttpResponseMessage returned after a redirection caused by failed auth?

Comment: @Jimi The content that I pass to PostAsync is not null, it has 220 bytes of data and headers. After I review request message from received response, content is null because GET cannot have content. The server gives away 400 in response to any GET so I don't think it's the auth issue.

Comment: Remarks section of [HttpResponseMessage.RequestMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.requestmessage)

Comment: @Jimi Yes, you're right. The server literally redirects me to the same page, but using GET request this time. I have no idea why does this happen or why does it work fine with postman (I copied all the headers). Thank you, you can post an answer so I can verify

Comment: Well, I'm glad it helped to narrow down the issue (of course this kind of redirection sets the method to `GET`), but my comment doesn't solve the problem. You should (IMO) post an answer yourself when you have determined what causes the issue in the first place, otherwise it's just *words*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so the issue was actually with server.

It redirected all the requests with URLs not ending with "/", like `http://address.com/page` to the same address but ending with "/" - `http://address.com/page/`, and lost the method and content in process.

As @Jimi mentioned, the RequestMessage field in HttpResponseMessage contains the info about the last request that reached the server, therefore initial request data was lost, and I mistook it for HttpClient making wrong requests.