# HttpRequestMessage somehow always results in a GET Method

Tags: c#, post, dotnet-httpclient, nopcommerce

Currently Im building a shipment plugin for NopCommerce. In this particular case I have to Authenticate with target client Rest API. For this purpose I have created a (test) Authentication Method.

FYI: The endpoint is working fine with Postman, also changing to PUT/Delete for example also works fine. Only the POST method is being altered to GET. ALWAYS!

Also the following Stack Overflow question seems like the problem I'm currently experiencing, but not the solution.

[httpClient.PostAsync() performs GET request anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62579558/httpclient-postasync-performs-get-request-anyway)

The Method:

```
public async Task<string> PostHttpReqMessageAsync()
    {
        DHLApiRequestModel model = new DHLApiRequestModel()
        {
            UserId = _dhlSettings.UserID,
            Key = _dhlSettings.Key,
            AccountNumber = new List<string>()
            {
                _dhlSettings.AccountNumber
            }
        };

        string requestMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
        HttpContent content = new StringContent(requestMessage, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        HttpRequestMessage httpReqMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "authenticate/api-key")
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Post,
            Content = content
        };

        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await _httpClient.SendAsync(httpReqMessage);
            if (httpResponseMessage.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                return await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

The result when in debug:

> Method: GET, RequestUri: 'http://api-dp.nl/authenticate/api-key', Version: 1.1, Content: `<null`>, Headers:

Comment: What does "when in debug" mean specifically? Are you certain that the remote side isn't redirecting your POST to a GET? I'd be very surprised if this was an issue with your code -- it looks fine (you're repeating `HttpMethod.Post` twice, but that's just smell, not an actual problem). Have you used Fiddler to observe exactly what's being sent?

Comment: Its hard to say this method is being called in another method used by NopCommerce when selecting a shipment method in checkout. But when I say in debug I mean debugging in localhost. What do you mean with remote side and redirecting? How can I see wheter im being redirected to a Get method? Thank you in advance. Also Ill remove the smell

Comment: I'm asking how you're check what requests the code is making. The server might be returning a `303` or `302`, and using that to ask the client to re-request with a different method (which HttpClient will do automatically). As I said, use Fiddler to observe exactly what requests are being sent

Comment: Hmm. when I live capture traffic with fidler. I get the following: HTTP: localhost:55390 /checkout/OpcSaveBilling/ http://localhost:55390/checkout/OpcSaveBilling/ 200 POST

Comment: Looks like it's correctly sending a POST, then?

Comment: Yes seems like it. But the URL is different. This is due to parent method though.

Comment: Alright so l called the method earlier in the Constructor. And I indeed get a 301 Moved Permantantly. With a POST Method

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [canton7](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1086121/canton7) I have a solution/fix. Both the problem and solution are strange but it seems to work now.

The `PostHttpReqMessageAsync()` Method the actual HttpClient is being triggered by the Parent method `GetShippingOptionResponse()` which in turn is being triggered by `GetShippingOptions()` NopCommerce native method.

So I instead of:

```
return _dhlService.GetShippingOptionResponse(getShippingOptionRequest);
```

I did:

```
var options = _dhlService.GetShippingOptionResponse(getShippingOptionRequest);
return options;
```

Seems to work now

Actual problem? Probably the 301. Im doing a POST method while NopCommerce is doing a GET method. Which causes I redirect I guess.